# django-userena mugshot: file is not found

Tags: python, django

Just started to learned django. 
In order to maintain user management I try to use Userena app (if I'm not mistaken, Userena is extension of django standard auth app).

I configured and deployed Userena into django based web site with no problem. However, the mugshot causes me a bit of a headache :)

I can register new user and choose a pic as mugshot. The pic is uploaded into default dir "mugshots" (which is created in the root of my project) and after that django can't find it - error 404.

I mean if I hit URL referring to the pic

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/laban/mugshots/2e0973e4d4.jpg
```

I get the reply

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/laban/mugshots/
Using the URLconf defined in pilot.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$
^accounts/ ^signup/$ [name='userena_signup']
^accounts/ ^signin/$ [name='userena_signin']
^accounts/ ^signout/$ [name='userena_signout']
^accounts/ ^password/reset/$ [name='userena_password_reset']
^accounts/ ^password/reset/done/$ [name='userena_password_reset_done']
^accounts/ ^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$ [name='userena_password_reset_confirm']
^accounts/ ^password/reset/confirm/complete/$
^accounts/ ^(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/signup/complete/$ [name='userena_signup_complete']
^accounts/ ^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$ [name='userena_activate']
^accounts/ ^activate/retry/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$ [name='userena_activate_retry']
^accounts/ ^(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/email/$ [name='userena_email_change']
^accounts/ ^(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/email/complete/$ [name='userena_email_change_complete']
^accounts/ ^(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/confirm-email/complete/$ [name='userena_email_confirm_complete']
^accounts/ ^confirm-email/(?P<confirmation_key>\w+)/$ [name='userena_email_confirm']
^accounts/ ^(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/disabled/$ [name='userena_disabled']
^accounts/ ^(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/password/$ [name='userena_password_change']
^accounts/ ^(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/password/complete/$ [name='userena_password_change_complete']
^accounts/ ^(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/edit/$ [name='userena_profile_edit']
^accounts/ ^(?P<username>(?!signout|signup|signin)[\.\w-]+)/$ [name='userena_profile_detail']
^accounts/ ^page/(?P<page>[0-9]+)/$ [name='userena_profile_list_paginated']
^accounts/ ^$ [name='userena_profile_list']
^mugshots/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, accounts/laban/mugshots/, didn't match any of these.
```

I guess, the root cause is some incorrect url mapping, but I have no idea how to fix that. Please, help! :)

the root urls.py is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from pilot import settings
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', include('zlab.pilot.index.urls')),
                       (r'^accounts/', include('userena.urls')),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'www.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^www/', include('www.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

# desperate copy/paste...
# Serve media files only in development
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^mugshots/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
   )
else:
    print "no server is configured to serve media files. Do it now."
```

EDITED:
kinda solved...
just want to share my findings.

1st, update settings.py with MEDIA_ROOT. Set MEDIA_ROOT pointing to absolute location on your file system. for example:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/project'
```

2nd, update url patterns. Add

```
url(r'^accounts/[\.\w-]+/(mugshots/.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
url(r'^accounts/[\.\w-]+/edit/(mugshots/.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    }),
```

I wonder, if I've done this correctly?
I wonder, if I've missed that in userena docs?
I wonder, is this so obvious for everybody? :)

Comment: how your root urls.py

Comment: @karthikr I just updated my post with urls.py

Comment: Your URL patterns  does not match the URL you are trying to hit. Try `http://localhost:8000/mugshots/2e0973e4d4.jpg`

Comment: right! I thought so too :)
but such request gets another  "not found"
"2e0973e4d4.jpg" does not exist

but I bet this jpg does exist! it is on my local file system...